# Displaying MySQL data in a specific format

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm retrieving a set of location names from a MySQL database using PHP and displaying them on a page. It looks like this.

[image]

The code I have written displays the results one after the other from top down.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php

require_once("db_handler.php");

$conn = iniCon();
$db = selectDB($conn);

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM location_categories";
$result3 = mysql_query($query, $conn);

?>

<div id="choseLoc">
Locations <br/><br/>
    <table border="0">
        <?php
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result3))
        {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><? echo $row["Name"]; ?></td>
            <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="<? echo $row['Loc_Code']; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </table>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="buttons">
    <input type="reset" value="Clear" /> <input type="submit" value="Save" name="savebtn" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Now if there are many records, displaying it like that would not be very attractive. I want to display the results like this.

[image]

How can I display results in this format?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this for your inner table

```
<table border="0">
        <?php
$a = 0;

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result3))
        {
if($a++ %4 == 0) echo "<tr>";
        ?>

            <td><? echo $row["Name"]; ?></td>
            <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="<? echo $row['Loc_Code']; ?>" /></td>
        <?php
if($a %4 == 0) echo "</tr>";
        }
        ?>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can float each one to the left, as long as #choseLoc is 4 times the width of the inner divs, the floats will lay them out for you.

```
<div id="choseLoc" style="width:800px;">

    Locations<br/><br/>

    <?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result3)){
        ?>
        <div style="float:left; width:200px;">
            <?php echo $row["Name"]; ?> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $row['Loc_Code']; ?>" />
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    ?>

</div>
```